# IF statement / For Loop dilemma for formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

So I have been stuck on this problem for a while now. I am trying to replicate this formula below within Python:

```
 FINAL UPPERBAND = IF( (Current BASICUPPERBAND < Previous FINAL
 UPPERBAND) or (Previous Close > Previous FINAL UPPERBAND))
                     THEN (Current BASIC UPPERBAND) ELSE Previous FINALUPPERBAND)
```

My problem is that is throwing me off is how to create FINAL UPPERBAND when it is used within the If statement too. For reference BASIC UPPERBAND and CLOSES are their own dataframes which is making it a bit trickier too. The only way around this I can think is a for loop but the dataframes are pretty big so going to take ages.

I have tried other things such as pandas.where apply and things like this `final_uppers[(basic_uppers < basic_uppers.shift(1))] = basic_uppers` which when I add together give me mostly the correct answers but about 1/4 are wrong. And I believe this is due to filling the rows not in order. This is what I have now, but like I say there are still values that are incorrect:

```
final_uppers = pd.DataFrame(columns=closes.columns, index=closes.index)
final_uppers = final_uppers.fillna(0)
final_uppers[(basic_uppers < basic_uppers.shift(1))] = basic_uppers
final_uppers[(closes.shift(1) > final_uppers.shift(1))] = basic_uppers
final_uppers = final_uppers.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```

Edit: Could a Lambda function and .apply be used? Attempted a go but just get DataFrame is ambiguous.

Any help would be appreciated, or if someone could help me with looping through just to test how long it would take using a loop. But any ideas of how to get around this would be appreciated. :)

Maybe something like this may work:

```
final_uppers = pd.DataFrame(columns=closes.columns, index=closes.index)
final_uppers = final_uppers.fillna(0)

for i in range(1, len(final_uppers)):
    if (basic_uppers.iloc[i] < final_uppers[i-1]) | (closes.iloc[i-1] > final_uppers[i-1]):
        final_uppers.append(basic_uppers.iloc[i])
    else:
        final_uppers.append(final_uppers[i-1])
final_uppers = final_uppers
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data can be given as a list of dictionaries, then I suppose something like the following is what you want?

```py
lst = [{'basic_upperband': 5, 'close': 23, 'final_upperband': 0},
       {'basic_upperband': -2, 'close': 20},
       {'basic_upperband': 2, 'close': 19},
       {'basic_upperband': 1, 'close': 25}]

for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    if lst[i]['basic_upperband'] < lst[i-1]['final_upperband'] or lst[i-1]['close'] < lst[i-1]['final_upperband']:
        lst[i]['final_upperband'] = lst[i]['basic_upperband']
    else:
        lst[i]['final_upperband'] = lst[i-1]['final_upperband']

print(lst)
```

If your data is already a dataframe, you could loop through the rows and build the final_upperband column with something like the following

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'basic_upperband': 5, 'close': 23},
                   {'basic_upperband': -2, 'close': 20},
                   {'basic_upperband': 2, 'close': 19},
                   {'basic_upperband': 1, 'close': 25}])

final_upperband = [0]
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['basic_upperband'] < final_upperband[i-1] or df.iloc[i-1]['close'] < final_upperband[i-1]:
        final_upperband.append(df.iloc[i]['basic_upperband'])
    else:
        final_upperband.append(final_upperband[i-1])
df['final_upperband'] = final_upperband
```

Comment: Hiya, yes my data is currently already in seperate dataframes, so currently all basic upperband values are in a df, and all closes are in a df, then i want to create final upperband as its own df. Could you give a simple example of iterrows, have not used it before, would really appreciate it

Comment: Wasn't as easy with iterrows as I thought, so did another approach building the column and then adding it afterwards

Comment: Still not sure it will work for my situation. I have a DataFrame with all the Close prices in, and a seperate DataFrame for Basic Upperband, and I want to create a new DataFrame for Final Upperbands. My data is not in one dataframe under column names as your example shows, so in the if statement where you compare the column basic upperband, i need something that would check the actual dataframe containing all closes

Comment: well you could just merge the two dataframes - or if they always contain the same numbers of rows, you could simply change the name that is referenced, to use the name of your close dataframe.

Comment: Yes they always have the same number of rows. And merging might be difficult because I have 500 columns. How would I change the name though and still be able to go row by row, added an example to the question, haven't tested it yet tho

Comment: i am just looping over an index variable `i`, so that could reference anything. just replace `df.iloc[i]` with `closes.iloc[i]`

Comment: ok yes thats what I thought, just added an example, tested it and sadly got 2 errors. One was it was too ambiguous, so I changed or to |, then it said 'Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]'